# Xamarin forms save switch change to sqlite

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am new to xamarin and I am stuck with a problem.
I am making a todo app, where in the listview where you see the items you could set the task to done with a switch. The switch currently displays the saved value, so it is bound to the value from the database, but I can not see how to save the state if it gets changed.
As I see somehow I need to get the object from the switch, I appreciate the help.

```
<ListView x:Name="MainListView"
              ItemSelected="MainListView_OnItemSelected">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Label Text="{Binding Content}"></Label>
                        <Switch IsToggled="{Binding Done}" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"></Switch>
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

This is my custom ViewcCel where the value is bound.

```
public ToDoItem() { }

    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public string PicturePath { get; set; }
    public bool Done { get; set; }
```

This is the Entity.
The list is on the main page, with the page in the code behind i do other stuff, just in case here is the code https://github.com/benonymus/ToDoApp3

Comment: The bound instance needs to be able to trigger databinding refresh. Look into Reactive or Observable, INotifyPropertyChanged. Probably want to separate storage entity from binding source, e.g. use a viewmodel in between.

Answer (score 0):

You can have:

```
<Switch x:Name="my_switch" Toggled="Switch_Toggled" />
```

and in page:

```cs
public MyPage()
{
    my_switch.IsToggled = Done;
}

private void Switch_Toggled(object sender, ToggledEventArgs e)
{
    Done = my_switch.IsToggled;
}
```

Edit:

You can also try:

```
<Switch IsToggled="{Binding Done, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```